# How can i check for null property in object inline with ES 6 syntax?

Tags: javascript

I have one object with five properties and i need to take just three of them.For one of the properties i need to check if it is null value then it should be 'Unknown'.
The code will look like this

```
let obj = {
    name:"john",
    lastName:"doe",
    age:24,
    city:null

}

function getSomeProperties(obj) {
    let newObj = {
        name: obj.name,
        age:obj.age,
        city:obj.city == null ? 'unknown' : obj.city
    }
    console.log(newObj);
}

getSomeProperties(obj);
```

if i try to take only three properties inline then this works

```
function getSomeProperties(obj) {
    const newObj = (({name, age, city}) => ({name, age, city }))(obj);
    console.log(newObj);
}
```

but the problem is when i try inline to check if city is null like in the first case then i get error.

```
function getSomeProperties(obj) {
    const newObj = (({name, age, city}) => ({name, age, city == null ? 'unknown' : city }))(obj);
    console.log(newObj);
}
```

Can be this thing maked inline?

Comment: newObj = (({name, age, city}) => ({name, age, city : city == null ? 'unknown' : city }))(obj);

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it like this:

```
({name, age, city: city == null ? 'unknown' : city })
```

Or you use nullish coalescing operator:

```
({name, age, city: city ?? 'unknown' })
```

The same you can do above:

```
city: obj.city ?? 'unknown'
```

It checks if the left side is either `null` or `undefined`. If its the case it returns the value thats on the right side.

Remember `0` or `false` is not considered as nullish value.

In JavaScript, a nullish value is the value which is either `null` or `undefined`. Nullish values are always falsy.